# How do I remove the title attribute from images in Wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

My client is not too crazy about the tooltip you see when you hover on images in browsers like Safari. 
[image]

The tooltip displays the title attribute in the img tag, which Wordpress forces you to have. Removing the title value from the tag (easy to do with jQuery) still shows you a blank tooltip.

So I don't need a solution that does this:

```
<img title=" " src="foobar.png" />
```

I need a solution that does **this**:

```
<img src="foobar.png" />
```

I have searched all over the Internet, and [the answers that come close](http://www.kevinleary.net/remove-title-attributes-images-wordpress/) don't seem to work. I believe it can be done by overriding the Wordpress core function that generates the image tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a straight JavaScript solution this should work:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  imgs[i].removeAttribute('title');
}
```